# Xcode terminates when clicking on XIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I want to test my app in iOS 6. Currently I am using Xcode 6

I read some articles that state "you have to download older versions of Xcode (e.g. Xcode 5) and in Xcode 5 download the iOS Simulator 6 and then run in it."

But if I do it like that, I am getting the following errors for only specific XIB files like:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: From iOS 7 Xibs layout has been changed. So if you want to open Xibs in below Xcode 5 version than it may cause this issue.

Comment: No i want open in Xcode 5 with ios 6 simulator.please suggest me how to test app in ios 6 simulator with xcode 6.

Comment: Sorry My problem is to test app in ios 6 simulator with xcode 6.(or regardless of xcode)

Comment: You can perfectly test app in iOS 6 simulator with Xcode 6. What is the issue?

Comment: just by going xcode 5->preferences->downloads->ios 6.1 simulator.

Comment: how please suggest me the steps

Comment: You can not see iOS 6 simulator in device list when you run from Xcode because project `Deployment Target must be iOS 8 or greater`.

Comment: then is there any workaround?

Comment: I have never tried this, And I don't think there is any workaround. May be others will guide you some decent way.

Comment: in general how do you test  the app in ios 6 whether that is working fine or not to test the UI now a days.

Comment: Download >= Xcode 6.0 version. Open old project in this Xcode >> remove all warnings/errors/deprecations >> Clean-Build and check UI is working for iOS 6.0 simulator or not.

Comment: @kampai xcode 6 does not come with iOS 6 simulator. and there is no way of adding iOS 6 simulator to Xcode 6. if there is some special way to do this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You are usually able to copy simulators from one Xcode to another, effectively installing the iOS 6 simulator into Xcode 6 like you want to. However, in looking around, it seems as though Xcode 6 doesn't support simulators under iOS 7.

My recommendation would be to install Xcode 4 or 5 and run your app there, but it sounds like you've already developed some of your app using Xcode 6. If that is the case, you'll have a lot of warnings. It's not a good idea to develop an app in a newer version of Xcode then run in an older version. Apple tries to get out the bugs when updating your Xcode version, but I doubt they do much testing or work on supporting downgrading the version.

If your xib files aren't complicated, you might rebuild them in the older version of Xcode and try to run again. There's almost always something that changes in how Apple formats xib files with each version. I believe that's what's causing your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open xibs made in Xcode > 5 in Xcode 5, you will have to specifically save them in Xcode 5 format:

[image]

Of course, then you won't be able to use any modern features, e.g. size classes.